# Precision improvement for solution of the simplest low-pass filter

Tags: differential-equations, machine-precision

I solved the most basic low-pass filter using NDSolve in Mathematica and LTSpice. The solution provided by Mathematica seems to lack precision. I tried to deal with *WorkingPrecision* but I didn't manage to get it to improve the solution. Could you please help me with precision improvement?

Here is the electrical circuit in LTSpice:

[image: circuit]

The solution for potential difference across the capacitor C1 solved by LTSpice is below:

[image: LTspice_solution]

Here is my code in Mathematica:

```
freq = 10000;
vs[t_] = 20 + 30*Sin[2*Pi*freq*t];
r1 = 5;
c1 = 0.0001;
plotx = 1/freq*50;

sol = NDSolve[{vs[t] == r1*c1*vc1'[t] + vc1[t], vc1[0] == 0}, 
   vc1[t], {t, 0, 0.060}];
Plot[vc1[t] /. sol, {t, 0, plotx}]
```

which gives this Plot:

[image: Mathematica_plot]

As you can see from the plots above, the solution by LTSpice provides better precision by default.

Comment: Try increasing the setting of `PlotPoints` in `Plot[]`, e.g. `Plot[vc1[t] /. sol, {t, 0, plotx}, PlotPoints -> 45]`.

Comment: @J.M., that worked! And PlotPoints -> 15 worked as well. I added Mesh -> All to see each point on the plot. Could you explain the mechanism that Mathematica uses to choose a number of PlotPoints by default? I tried to find the value for PlotPoints that would correspond to the result without specifying PlotPoints, and I couldn't find it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the mechanism for automatically choosing `PlotPoints` does not seem to be publicly known.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just plotting issue. Try increasing number of plot points

```
Plot[vc1[t]/.sol,{t,0,plotx},
     PlotPoints->200,
     AxesOrigin->{0,0},
     Frame->True,
     GridLines->Automatic,GridLinesStyle->LightGray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you and J. M. very much for the fast answer! It is indeed a plotting issue.